# ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64 : Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently I downloaded Xcode 9 and created one sample iPhone app but the app is not able to build as it shows the following error:

> ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture x86_64

I searched on net about same and tried few ways like deleting derived data, restarting Xcode but still not fix the problem.

Anybody has faced similar issue?

Comment: was the app created with another xcode?

Comment: No. But I also opened old projects with new xcode they are running fine..

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Found out that "AppDelegate" wasn't part of "target" membership.

Comment: can you please elaborate it more. I could not get what you identified.

Comment: Jesus. Can't believe this was the issue

Comment: @user6159419 He means that in XCode, click on your project in the project navigator, then go to Build Phases, then go to Compile Sources and make sure that AppDelegate is included among the Compile Sources

Comment: click on AppDelegate->Go to File Inspector->Check in target membership

Comment: Add The AppDelegate.swift in the Compile Source by clicking on plus icon locate In your Target project

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect it could be as simple as that, the proj file is messed up during rebase in my case and newly added MyApplication.swift is not added to the target.

Comment: Yes! Similar was preventing my Project with a WatchApp from building because the WatchAppDelegate was not included as part of any target.

Answer (score 95):

Adding `@main` fixed the issue.

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
}
```

`@UIApplicationMain` was prior to `Swift 5.3`.

Comment: I accidentally commented out that line, and uncommenting it solved my problem!

Comment: Explanation about the difference between `@UIApplicationMain` and `@main`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429098/what-is-the-differnce-between-main-and-uiapplicationmain

Answer (score 39):

I've been faced with same problem. here is how i fixed it:
Select your Project then go to Build Setting -> Search Mach-O Type Change to -> Bundle
. hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks the error was not helpful at all. I don't know what I would do without stackoverflow.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I missed `@UIApplicationMain` in `AppDelegate.swift`. Adding it right before `class AppDelegate`, my app started building again

Comment: Due to old laptop (therefore stuck on Catalina), I am trying to back-port a Big Sur (etc. Xcode and Macbook Pro) to Catalina on Macbook Pro (mid 2012) which sits precariously between the two development platforms.  This was the last build (linker) issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  ...
}
```

**Swift 5**

Make sure you have @main at the beginning of your appDelegate class.

Answer (score 3):

Please Open your `AppDelegate.swift` class and check if `@UIApplicationMain` is written or not. If not then add this line of code in this class below the import `UIKit "@UIApplicationMain"`.

Same like this:
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
}

Answer (score 3):

Make sure "AppDelegate" is part of "target" membership.

**Click *AppDelegate* -> *Attribute inspector* -> *Check Target membership***

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add `@UIApplicationMain` to fix the issue. As well as what it does internally you can do the same by your own. In that case, you don't need to add `@UIApplicationMain`. Simply create one swift file name it main and put the below code inside it. It will work as expected.

```
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, 
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)), nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

Answer (score 2):

## For Framework (Dynamic Library)

If you're facing this error while building a framework, then select the **Dynamic Library** Under the **Build Settings > Mach-O Type**.

#### Tested on the Xcode Version 11.6 (11E708)

Best.

Answer (score 2):

in my case `@main` was commented .

your `AppDelegate` should be like this :

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I accendtly removed my appDelegate file :)

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in appDelegate

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

Comment: Edit your answer and insert more so that it is going to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of these answers helped.
The problem occurred, when **archiving the release build**.

### Preview Assets.xcassets

I moved `Preview Assets.xcassets` to the root folder of the project, so, you have to move it back to the separate folder

1. In your root folder `App/` [create a folder named](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CtSG.png) `Preview Content`
2. [Drag & drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWJn.png) `Preview Assets.xcassets` to `Preview Content`
3. [Go to your target settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAsRO.png)
4. [Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnEQ.png) `Build Settings` -> `All` and `Combined`
5. [Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gyju.png) for `Development Assets`
6. [Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjjX4.png) the path to `"App/Preview Content"`

Tested on `XCode 14.2 (14C18)`

I'm not able no upload photos yet, sadly, but I hope links to them is enough!