# Application launch did not return a valid pid nor a launch error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, simulator

My app installs fine on the simulator and I can attach the process after opening it manually but it won't run from the debug play button without throwing the error below.

I've tried all the tricks I know (deleting the derived data and re-compiling, commenting out some code here and there, exhaustive searches for keywords).

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
Details

Application launch for '------' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: No such process
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.0 (19A339)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 845;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.6.1 (Build 20G224)
Xcode 13.1 (19466) (Build 13A1030d)
Timestamp: 2021-11-18T16:14:15-07:00
```

Comment: I had the same error. It was resolved by simply restarting the simulator.

Comment: I have the same error, neither of the two provided solutions work for me.

Comment: My app doesn't start even manually, it crashes

Answer (score 61):

Faced the same problem. The problem was that the simulator was launched before Xcode.

Solution: Just close the simulator and build the project again

Comment: Yeah, just restarting the simulator fixed it for me

Comment: Hours wasted cleaning this and that only to find this...

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: does not work for me, i am using M1. Can anyone helo ?

Comment: Same, does not work for me using M1

Answer (score 29):

Ok turns out this mystery no-name Environment Variable was checked in the scheme.  I unchecked it and it worked.

[image]

Comment: not sure how much time u have spent on this but saved my time thanks

Comment: I had same issue. I remember yesterday I accidentally click the + button here though I was supposed to click the other + button under the Arguments Passed On Launch. And this added a blank Environment Variable entry which I didn't notice. The app launched fine on the phone where I tested it, but when today tried to run it in the simulator, it started giving this error. Thanks for pointing this out. I removed this blank Environment Variable and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I spent hours hunting this error, and you solved it.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, even if I wasn't running it under Rosetta, I had to install it. To do that, run this script:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

or this if you want to skip the license agreement:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Comment: I was having this issue with CircleCI not attaching to a simulator device. I had tried everything and nothing would work even while an identical local setup was working fine. I added this command after my `pod install` step in CCI but before the Fastlane run and it finally started working. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8):

There seem to be multiple causes of this error.  I'm running on an M1 Max / macOS Monterey.  I tried some of the above solutions but found that they were either not applicable or had no effect.  In the end, [the answer (for my config) was here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848389/m1-mac-react-native-app-simulator-xcode-did-not-return-a-valid-pid-nor-a-launch) -- **install Rosetta**.  This was also what Xcode had been prompting me to do at every launch.  I am running an app that uses Cocapods.

Comment: with rosetta launch. it works fine for M1

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution was to change the Mach-O Type to bundle, then run the app again (same error) and change it back to Executable again.

[image: Your Target > Build Settings]

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

Comment: When I change it back to executable it throws me error of entry point (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648834/ld-entry-point-main-undefined-for-architecture-x86-64-xcode-9)

Answer (score 2):

I also want to run the app in emulator. Changing the scheme's Build Configuration to **Debug** solved my issue.

Comment: This was the fix that I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the `Mach-O` type (which was not set) but it did not help.
Restarting the simulator solved it (it was open before the Xcode was opened).

Comment: All other options were already in place, restarting simulator worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue and solved it by running $ `flutter clean && flutter run`. The Xcode workspace just needed clearing.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by removing `arm64` from the Excluded Architectures in the Build Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode open Simulator-> Device -> Erase All contents and settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to run unit test and similar error shows up after lunching app on the simulator.

What worked for me is that I didn't notice the compiler error while building the unit test target. After fixing the test target build issue, app runs fine again. So, make sure the project is building without any error.

Comment: and yes, even though test target shows that build is successful, there were compiler errors "issue navigator".

Answer (score 0):

If your error started suddenly, just think of the action you performed earlier that might have caused this.
I had added libc++.tbd library in incorrect xcode/simulator location. Removing that fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple clean

Cmd + shift + k