# M1 Mac React Native app simulator Xcode did not return a valid pid nor a launch error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

`Application launch for 'au.com.appname' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code: 3 Failure Reason: No such process User Info: { DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-01-25 12:02:41 +0000"; IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;`

I just got given an M1 Mac by work. I have not installed Rosetta. I do not wish to install Rosetta. I managed to install all the pods and added arm64 to the excluded arch of the Pods project in Xcode, the app builds and installs on the simulator, but when it opens on the simulator, it immediately closes, and Xcode shows the above error. Is there something I am forgetting to do?

Thanks

Comment: "*I have not installed Rosetta. I do not wish to install Rosetta.*" This seems a bit arbitrary to me - how do you know this is an issue relating to Rosetta in the first place? If it would solve your issue, why do you "*not wish to install Rosetta*"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application launch did not return a valid pid nor a launch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028040/application-launch-did-not-return-a-valid-pid-nor-a-launch-error)

Comment: It is something to do with M1. My team members have worked around the issue by running Rosetta and taking the performance hit. I do not wish to do so. Me saying that I have not installed it tells you that any code I am running is native to arm64 which is important information.

Comment: The other question is not relevant as it does not mention M1 or arm64 and these are definitely central to the problem - the repo runs flawlessly on Intel Macs or on M1 Macs with Rosetta enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. Although it was building under arm64, the simulator binary created was still x86, and it could not launch because there was no Rosetta.

Since my first attempt I installed Rosetta and ran Xcode under Rosetta so I could get on with development, but I tried again, and have it building under arm64 but running on the simulator in Rosetta, which is pretty close to not needing Rosetta. The final question is why an arm64 build is creating an x86 binary.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get this working without Rosetta? I tried following this guide but got the same problem as you, even though the author clearly did not. https://jimji1005.medium.com/building-react-native-ios-with-m1-without-rosetta-b7e626ccef0d
Like you, I don’t want to install Rosetta

Comment: If you have pods which do not implement the XCFramework then you cannot run it on the simulator without Rosetta, period. The biggest problem for the company I work at is that react-native-maps uses GoogleMaps pod which is not yet ready. But you can build without Rosetta and run it on a physical test device.