# Flutter app not running on iOS Simulator running on m2 processor

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

My Flutter app runs perfectly on M1 processor. Now, I have upgraded to the new M2 processor. After installing everything when I run the app on my iOS Simulator, I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           22.0s
Exception: Unable to launch uk.co.example.client on 01D40B66-5A9B-464E-882E-4EB9B762168F:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
No such process
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
    Application launch for 'uk.co.example.client' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
    No such process
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl launch 01D40B66-5A9B-464E-882E-4EB9B762168F uk.co.financemagic.client --enable-dart-profiling --start-paused --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

I tried cleaning flutter project. Cleaning build folder from xcode. Removing pods file, PodFile.lock. Nothing seemed to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error could happen for many reasons, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70028040/application-launch-did-not-return-a-valid-pid-nor-a-launch-error. Maybe you can find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything and failing. I fixed it by installing rosetta. Just open terminal and run the following command:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put arm64 for simulator
OR
You can set arm64 in pods.

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxy6B.png)
end
end

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked to make sure your build configuration is set to debug and not release? I hand't noticed mine changed to release after switching laptops

[image]

Comment: I have checked it again. It is set to debug.

Comment: If you're going to ask questions I suggest you using the comment section below the question. Answers should only be 100% the expected answer without a back and forward guessing.